# DataSnapshot and OnceAysnc - FirebaseXamarin

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin

I want to know. What is the best way of retrieving data from firebase. Do i have to use DataSnapshot to fetch data or OnceAsync. It seems to me they are working similar. I might not be 100% correct  but do they work the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do i have to use DataSnapshot to fetch data or OnceAsync. It seems to me they are working similar. I might not be 100% correct but do they work the same?

Yes you're right, they are working similar, they're all used to query data from firebase database. For the problem of which one to use, it depends on which lib do you want to installed to your package.

For the package in official [GooglePlayServicesComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/) of xamarin, it doesn't have a method named `OnceAsync`. It's a converter of the original Java SDK for Android platform version, so the methods and fields are basically the same as the Google's official document of [Firebase Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), the goodness is that you can follow this google's document to use this xamarin lib to develop your app.

The `OnceAsync` method is included in this [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin) package, which as the author explained, is a **Light weight wrapper for Firebase Realtime Database REST API.**

So it is built based on the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) of Google Firebase Database. If we don't use this package and in the meanwhile want to use its rest api for development, usually we need to create for example `HttpClient` to post the get.